# Is QTGMC still the best deinterlacer?

Tags: video, video-quality

From reading various video forums, QTGMC seems to have a reputation as being one of the best tools for deinterlacing video (at least from an open-source perspective), with Yadif in second place.

1. Is QTGMC still as highly regarded in 2019?
2. Are there other tools (open source or otherwise) that come close or even exceed the quality from QTGMC?
3. Has anyone done an in-depth quality comparison?

Comment: Would also love to know.